# Can we create a tag for postgres-9.3?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

There should be a postgres-9.3 tag for tagging questions, right?

Comment: have you got a question in mind?

Comment: All the question that I have asked on DBA are 9.3 related.  The latest one is http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/postgres-9-3-postgres-fdw-replication-and-create-server-will-it-work

Comment: ah, OK, the tag is [tag:postgresql-9.3]

Comment: Would this be different from the [tag that already exists](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.3), [tag:postgresql-9.3]?

Comment: Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a preexisting synonym for postgresql<--postgres, and I've [added synonyms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for the more recent specific releases too.

[image]